# "pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0" reports older version

Tags: libraries, configure, pkg-config

I have Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit. I am trying to compile an application from source code. It gives me an error message during linking in `make` process though `./autogen.sh` and `./configure` passed without errors. I got this error `undefined reference to g_variant_parse_error_quark` I read that that function `g_variant_parse_error_quark` added to glib2 in 2.39. I checked out installed packages and found that libglib version is 2.40.0 in my system. However

```
 pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0
```

reports `2.38.2`

It appears that I have at least two different glib2 installed. I might have manually installed glib2 from source in the past.

How can I fix that problem and let my system use correct latest library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I guessed it stemmed from conflicting multiple libraries. 
When I run

```
 echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

it returned empty line

Then I searched for

```
  locate glib-2.0.pc
```

and I got

```
  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/spice-client-glib-2.0.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc
```

I also run

```
  pkg-config --debug --modversion glib-2.0
```

to find which directories were searched for

I looked in the `glib-2.0.pc` files and checked out the version numbers.

I located the correct `glib-2.0.pc` file

then I run

```
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/
```

after then `./autogen.sh` and `make`

went smoothly